# HQL JoinTable not accessible 2

Tags: hql

I have a code like that

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }) @JoinTable(name = "AssignedBook_Person", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_Id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_Id") })

As you see my JoinTable name is AssignedBook_Person and i want to take some data from it with that code

List borrowedBook = session createQuery(" from AssignedBook_Person ")
.setCacheable(true).list();

But it gives this error "AssignedBook_Person is not mapped "

Does anybody have any idea how i can solve JoinTable problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query directly database tables via HQL , because it does not operate to database tables - it operates to entities. That is main idea of object relational mapping.

Join table contains data about relation between Book and Person, so data can be fetched by selecting instances of one of those and then examining related entities.

If only raw data in join_table is needed, native query can be used:

```
session.createSQLQuery(SELECT person_id, book_id FROM AssignedBook_Person);
```

Comment: But my problem is about Map AssignedBook_Person table to hibernate.cfg.xml. It does not find AssignedBook_Person in xml.

Comment: You do not have to add table to hibernate.cfg.xml. It is still a join table, not the table that maps directly to entity, and that's why there is limitations, as described in answer.